# Javascript - Close Pixelate Script - How to add right click to save in JPG?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

the script is the one from David De Sandro http://close-pixelate.desandro.com/

this is my HTML

```
<body>
<article>
 <figure>
  <img id="image" id="circles" class="portrait" src="img/original.jpg" alt="none" />
  <figcaption>Caption Here</figcaption>
 </figure>
</article>
```

and this the Close Pixelate effect on the IMG

```
<script>

    var pixelations = {
      'circles' : [
    { shape: 'diamond', resolution: 30, size: 31 },
    { shape: 'diamond', resolution: 30, offset: 15 },
    { resolution: 30, alpha: 0.5 }
      ],
        var docReady = function() {

      for ( var key in pixelations ) {
        var img = document.getElementById( key ),
            options = pixelations[key];
        if ( img ) { 
          img.closePixelate( options )
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', docReady, false);  

</script>
```

And this gives me the effect on the image, but what I need to add a Right click and save the JPG (with effects applied)?

---edit---

If I use this

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");                // Get the context for the canvas.
    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");      // Get the data as an image.
}

var image = document.getElementById("image");  // Get the image object.
image.src = myImage;
```

I have this problem: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: Please try and do some research before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039316/save-a-html-canvas-image

Comment: So if the image has been modified to your liking, what's preventing you from simply doing right-click-save-as on the img element? If the img has been replaced by an html canvas, you can create a .png dataURL of the canvas with theCanvas.toDataURL(“image/jpeg”).

Comment: still trying to make it works

Comment: There is no element with the ID `image` in the HTML code you have shown.