# Format of image downloaded in client-side

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am downloading images in html page using javascript. This works in latest firefox and chrome browsers.

What I would like to know is the format in which the image will be saved? Though, we can give formats in file name like `image.png`, will it be saved in png format?

The source of the image is SVG graphics, so this image is completely generated and downloaded in client-side. I am using the following code for downloading:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
svg = $("#container").html();
canvg(canvas, svg);
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = image;
downloadLink.download = "imge.png";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

Here `image` is the javascript variable in which the image is stored.

Comment: The format depends on what format the server is actually returning.  What is the content-type from the server?  Is the binary data actually in PNG format already?  Just saving the file isn't going to convert it if it isn't.

Comment: @David, This is not an image returned from server, I am drawing it in client-side using HTML5 SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be saved in the format of the original image. Browsers do not do image conversion.

Comment: yes, this is my question, I am using svg to create the image in client-side, I'm definitely sure the converted image is not SVG. I am using "Canvas.toDataURL for converting the image to data. I'll post my full code for conversion and explain it more clearly.

Comment: Canvas images are saved as PNG. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039316/save-a-html-canvas-image

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I found the reason why it is saved as png, canvas.toDataURL("image/png") and other mime types that can be used.